# getview not getting called

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, listadapter

This is the main activity calling list adapter the app crashes everytime since getview is never called therefore the list is never loaded.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */

**DummySectionFragment**

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
       //itcItems = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.streamList);
        //itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);




        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(getActivity());
        task.execute("http://findaway.in/card/restlist.xml");
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}


static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Data> > {

    Activity mContext;
    //Response response;
   public  MyAsyncTask(Activity context) {

     this.mContext=context;
    }
    protected List<Data> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // Debug the task thread name
        Log.d("ITCRssReader", "inside");

        try {
            // Create RSS reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);
            Log.d("ITCRssReader", "inside1");
            // Parse RSS, get items
            //Log.d("ITCRssReader", rssReader.getItems().get(3).getName());
            return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ITCRssReader", "error");
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Data> result) {
        Log.d("RESULT", result.get(3).getName());
        // Get a ListView from main view
       ListView itcItems = (ListView)mContext.findViewById(R.id.streamList);
       ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(mContext,R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, result);             
        // Create a list adapter
        itcItems.setAdapter(la);
    }
}
}`
```

this is my code for adapter
"Log.d("list",obj.getName())" never gets called
**ListAdapter**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data>    {
    Context context;
    // List values
    List<Data> foodList;
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource , List<Data> result) {
    super(context, resource, result);
    //Log.d("RESULT2", result.get(3).getName());
    this.context = context;
    this.foodList = result;
    Log.d("RESULT2", foodList.get(3).getName());
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //View rowView=convertView;
     // ImageHolder holder = null;

      Data obj = foodList.get(position);
      Log.d("list",obj.getName());

      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,parent,false);
      TextView n = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
      TextView d = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.discount);
      TextView l = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.Type);
      n.setText(obj.getName());
      d.setText(obj.getDiscount());
      l.setText(obj.getLocation());


          return rowView;

       }


}
```

Comment: 'the app crashes' is not very helpful. You have to post the LogCat error message, which by the way will help you understand what's going wrong.

Comment: http://snag.gy/nel1p.jpg here's the logcat screenshot

Answer (score 1):

There are a few bad practices here… but let me point you to the possible culprit:

Your AsyncTask should not create the adapter. Your AsyncTask should fetch data and let the Fragment know: hey, here's fresh data, you can now do whatever you want with it.

Also, like it has already been stated, leave the AsyncTask out of "onActivityCreated".

The error is likely here in your onPostExecute:

```
 Log.d("RESULT", result.get(3).getName());
```

Either result is null or the 4th item of your results list doesn't have a name.

Always check for Null.

Use an observer/listener pattern to notify about events.

**UPDATE**: 
Since it seems like that null is a little below…

You are creating an adapter in a method (onPostExecute) that belongs to an object (AsyncTask) that is dying very soon, and by keeping that adapter you're keeping your asynctask, which in turn has a reference to an Activity (*Bad Idea*), which is leaking memory.

But the adapter is dying when your whole AsyncTask is finally garbage collected of course. Because like I said, you should not create the adapter in the async task.

Move that logic out of the way.

on OnPostExecute let your fragment know that there's new data.

And in your callback do something like…

```
if ( mListAdapter == null ) {
    mListAdapter = new Adapter…
    mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
}
else {
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: result.get(3).getName() is displaying the required name in log means result list is getting generated fine. Problem is adapter not setting up since it is returning null.

Comment: Since i am new to android can you tell me the code modification i am required to make.?  I got your point but dont know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you called async task in oncreateview() method.

- Because oncreateview() method returns view for your fragment, after it returns view for your fragment then only your fragment views get loaded.
- since you added async task in oncreateview, async task is executing before your fragment gets views. so in onPostExecute() your listview won't work.
- **solution** : Execute your async task in onActivitycreated() method of your fragment.

Comment: I updated my code according to your suggestion its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try executing async task in onAttach method of fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);

    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(activity);
    task.execute("http://findaway.in/card/restlist.xml");
}
```

Change your onPostExecute to following:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(List<Data> result) {
        Log.d("RESULT", result.get(3).getName());
        // Get a ListView from main view
       ListView itcItems = (ListView)DummySectionFragment.this.getView().findViewById(R.id.streamList);
       ListAdapter la = new ListAdapter(mContext,R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, result);             
        // Create a list adapter
        itcItems.setAdapter(la);
    }
```

> You are creating an adapter in a method (onPostExecute) that belongs
>   to an object (AsyncTask) that is dying very soon, and by keeping that
>   adapter you're keeping your asynctask, which in turn has a reference
>   to an Activity (Bad Idea), which is leaking memory.

I don't agree with that adapter object does not belong to AsyncTask object as it is created inside onPostExecute and is assigned to a local variable keeping adapter object is not a big problem but the thing is creating new adapter each time you get a data is not a good idea instead as @martin mentioned you should only create one adapter and on data change notify that adapter.

Comment: Tried doing it not working :( OnPost is giving null pointer exception as usual

Comment: instead of calling findViewById on activity try calling it on view from fragment

Comment: Still not working . you should probably read martins comment above and then if possible tell me the code modification i need to make.

Comment: do you have a streamList in fragment_main_dummy??